# 1976 TRW Defense and Space Systems Group font

Tags: fonts, typefaces, monospace

Is there a freely available rendering of the font used in this [Paper](https://static.aminer.org/pdf/PDF/000/361/405/software_requirements_are_they_really_a_problem.pdf)? Is it some "standard" typewriter font used in 70s by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I immediately thought, "IBM Selectric" when I looked at the paper you linked to.

I did a little searching and found someone had scanned their IBM Selectric typeball fonts: 
[http://typebarhead.blogspot.com/2012/04/ibm-selectric-typeball-fonts.html][1]

I'm pretty darn sure it's Letter Gothic 12. Look at the lowercase L and R for comparison. Looks the same to me.